# Slow to add datatable to comboboxes

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a form with five comboboxes that has the same datatable added to each, this datatable is created from data pulled from an XML file. It all works, however, the form takes several seconds to load and I've traced the slowest part of the code to be the last section where the ComboBox.DataSource = DataTable. Does anyone know why this takes so long?

```
Dim GuideDataTable As New DataTable
GuideDataTable.Columns.Add ("Text", GetType (String))
GuideDataTable.Columns.Add ("Index", GetType (Integer))
GuideDataTable.Rows.Add ("", 0)

For ItemIndex = 1 To CountNodes("guidecomponents")
    GuideDataTable.Rows.Add(ReadNode("guidecomponents", "name", "index", ItemIndex), ItemIndex)
Next

GuideDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Text"
GuideDataTable = GuideDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable

GuideComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text"
GuideComboBox1.ValueMember = "Index"
GuideComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Text"
GuideComboBox2.ValueMember = "Index"
GuideComboBox3.DisplayMember = "Text"
GuideComboBox3.ValueMember = "Index"
GuideComboBox4.DisplayMember = "Text"
GuideComboBox4.ValueMember = "Index"
GuideComboBox5.DisplayMember = "Text"
GuideComboBox5.ValueMember = "Index"

GuideComboBox1.BindingContext = New BindingContext
GuideComboBox2.BindingContext = New BindingContext
GuideComboBox3.BindingContext = New BindingContext
GuideComboBox4.BindingContext = New BindingContext
GuideComboBox5.BindingContext = New BindingContext

GuideComboBox1.DataSource = GuideDataTable
GuideComboBox2.DataSource = GuideDataTable
GuideComboBox3.DataSource = GuideDataTable
GuideComboBox4.DataSource = GuideDataTable
GuideComboBox5.DataSource = GuideDataTable
```

Comment: Roughly how many rows are there in the datatable?

Comment: I don't get the use of `BindingContext` here.

Comment: I am not understating something here… IF you have five (5) combo boxes, and, all five (5) combo boxes have the “SAME” `DataSource` `GuideDataTable`… THEN… ALL the combo boxes would “always” reflect the “SAME selected” value. IF you select item 2 in `GuideComboBox1`… THEN ALL the combo boxes (1-5) will now have item 2 as the selected item. This applies if ANY combo box changes… i.e. ALL the combo boxes would ALWAYS have the “SAME selected” item. If it is your intention to have all the combo boxes always containing the same "selected" value, then why five combo boxes? Why not a single combo box?

Comment: If you want each combo box to contain the same values yet work “independently”, then, you will need to “copy” or “create” a NEW `DataSource` for each combo box. Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: Thank you all. There are currently 29 rows added to the datatable from an XML file (it might grow but not by much).

Comment: The BindingContext prevents all the comboboxes displaying the same value when one is changed. I'm not sure this is best practice but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should step through the code and see where it is slow. It is probably in retrieval of the data, as setting the datasource is not a demanding task, unless there is a large amount of data.

If there are a lot of rows, you can use an async method to populate the comboboxes. This will return the UI thread so not disrupt the user.

Also you can clean the code up slightly:

- The `GuideComboBox1.BindingContext = New BindingContext` is unnecessary. You can just use the datasource property.
- As there are 4 comboboxes with identical data and display values, you can create a method that has has a combo box parameter. That way you don't have to duplicate your code so much. The following code calls all the combo boxes in the form (or user control):

```
For Each box In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)
     SetDatasource(box, GuideDataTable)
Next
```

Be aware that the above only calls comboxes that have no parent. You need to replace `Me` with the parent control (e.g. a panel)

If you have many combo boxes for different data, you can narrow that further by adding a tag to each box that needs a specific datasource and referencing that in the `For` statement. E.g.

```
For Each box In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox).Where(Function(x) x.Tag = "my tag name")
     SetDatasource(box, GuideDataTable)
Next
```

Method:

```
Private Sub SetDatasource(box As ComboBox, dataSource As DataTable)
   box.ValueMember = "Index"
   box.DisplayMember = "Text"
   box.DataSource = dataSource
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Julian, I appreciate your comments regarding the repetition and I've modified my code as you suggested, though I'm sorry I don't understand your comment about using the DataSource property instead of the BindingContext?

Comment: I'm only adding 29 lines (same for each ComboBox) and by using Stopwatches I traced the slow portion of the code to the last section with the five '''GuideComboBox1.DataSource = GuideDataTable''' lines. This measures at 381 milliseconds.

Comment: This would not be too bad on its own but I have another five similar panels each with five ComboBoxes drawing in different data from the XML file.